# Kotlin: is it possible to throw exception in when block as last statement?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

It is possible to throw exception in when block inside function? I would like to write something like that:

```
    fun generateStatus(response: Response?, mode : Byte, deviceState : Int, timestamp: Long) : Status {
        return when {
            deviceState != 1 -> Status(null, timestamp, STATUS_NOT_READY, -1, null)
            mode != 0 -> Status(null, timestamp, STATUS_CPU_OFF_OR_IN_BOOTLOADER, -1, null)
            response == null -> Status(null, timestamp, STATUS_NO_INFORMATION, -1, null)
            else -> {
                ...
                if(response.operationID != STATUS) 
                    throw IllegalArgumentException("Wrong status response operation id!")
            }
        }
    }
```

but IDE (Android studio) shows error: type mismatch, required Status, found Unit.

Comment: It will work if all branches in your `else` block throw an exception, but you have it after a condition check so otherwise your `else` will return `Unit`.

Comment: Throw an exception or return a `Status`.

Comment: Oh, I see,my fault, it is little weird to me to operate with when and if that are expressions with return types without return keyword and IDE warning confused me. For java code warning from Android Studio for same situation would be "missing return statement", however for Kotlin where Unit is a type else brunch returns Unit or Nothing (Exception throw). Just confused by warning.